# node.js module (npm library) own directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

I develop a npm library which needs to scan own `./node_modules` dependency directory because they are automatically `required` within the code; which behaves like some plug-ins that is , once they are installed, they are detected automatically by the code.

So, firstly I need:

`var functionsDir = fs.readdirSync('./node_modules');`

This works good as long as I develop this library stand-alone with test.

However, once this library is used under a app or another modules, the `functionDir` points  not own `./node_modules` dir but the top level `./node_modules` of the project root.

How does this happen and what do I miss, and how to fix?

Thanks!

To make it short, how to obtain own node_modules directories which the module itself depends on in any environment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I should use `__dirname` of node.

Thanks.